# How can I compute model metrics during training with canned estimators?

Tags: tensorflow

Using Keras, one typically gets metrics (e.g. accuracy) as part of the progress bar for free. Using the example here:

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py

After running e.g.

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Keras will start fitting the model, and will show progress output with something like:

```
 3584/60000 [>.............................] - ETA: 10s - loss: 0.0308 - acc: 0.9905
```

Suppose I wanted to accomplish the same thing using a TensorFlow canned estimator -- extract the current accuracy for a classifier, and display that as part of a progress bar (done by e.g. a [SessionRunHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SessionRunHook)).

It seems like accuracy metrics aren't provided as part of the default set of operations on a graph. Is there a way I can manually add it myself with a session run hook?

(It looks like it's possible to add operations to the graph as part of the `begin()` hook, but I'm not sure how I can e.g. request the computation of the model accuracy there.)

Answer (score 0):

accuracy is one of the default metrics in canned classifiers. But it will be calculated by Estimator.evaluate call not by Estimator.train. You can create a for loop to do what you want:
  for ...
    estimator.train(training_data)
    metrics = estimator.evaluate(evaluation_data)

Comment: Ok, but what if one wants to add false positives?

Comment: @PawełSzczur I think you'd have to create a Custom Estimator if you want custom metrics.